# Large table with too many indexes stalls my app

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-design, index, postgresql-performance

PostgreSQL version: 13.10

My app has a notification feature, where users have a list of events that happened in relation to them (much like the Facebook notifications). Each notification is a row in my `notifications` table, with many columns (15) such as:

- `id`
- `recipient_id`
- `notification_type` : `'post_notification' | 'comment notification' | 'dm_notification' | ...`
- `post_id` : foreign key to a post, can be `NULL`
- `comment_id` : foreign key to comment on a post, can be `NULL`
- `user_id` : foreign key to another user, can be `NULL`
- ...

So for example, if a notification is of type `post_notification` the `comment_id`, `user_id` and other columns will be set to `NULL`.

Here is a (slightly redacted) `\d+` output:

```
       Column       |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('notifications_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 notification_type  | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                           | extended |              | 
 read               | boolean                        |           | not null | false                                     | plain    |              | 
 recipient_id       | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 comment_id         | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 topic_id           | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 user_id            | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 badge_id           | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 inserted_at        | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |                                           | plain    |              | 
 updated_at         | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |                                           | plain    |              | 
 post_id            | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 contest_id         | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 article_id         | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
 entity_nbr         | integer                        |           |          | 1                                         | plain    |              | 
 article_comment_id | bigint                         |           |          |                                           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "notifications_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "notifications_article_comment_id_index" btree (article_comment_id)
    "notifications_comment_id_index" btree (comment_id)
    "notifications_post_id_index" btree (post_id)
    "notifications_recipient_id_index" btree (recipient_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "notifications_article_comment_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_comment_id) REFERENCES article_comments(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_badge_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (badge_id) REFERENCES badges(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_comment_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (comment_id) REFERENCES comments(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_contest_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (contest_id) REFERENCES contests(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_follower_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_post_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_recipient_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (recipient_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "notifications_topic_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) REFERENCES topics(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Access method: heap
```

The feature has been working fairly well for a while, but is now hitting some sort of bottleneck. The table is reaching 13,000,000 records, and I am facing an indexing conundrum:

- Many foreign keys need to be indexed, because when deleting a related entity (a post, for example), the database must delete every notification tied to it. Without an index on the corresponding foreign key, the entity removal fails with a timeout, since it takes too long to retrieve the notifications that needed to be deleted
- But now, many writes to the `notifications` table fail with a timeout, as I believe that maintaining all these indexes has become too costly for writing into the table.

I have been going back and forth with removing and adding indexes trying to fix these two issues, but they seem to be utterly in conflict... Has anyone faced such a dilemma, and has any idea what is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Thanks! I added the relevant info I could think of.

Comment: The most helpful thing would be `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a slow execution.

Comment: Too much speculation, not enough known facts.  Maybe your timeouts are just unreasonable. What are they?  And for that matter, why are they?

Comment: Timeouts are at 15 seconds. They still occur when I raise the bar to 30, at which point they overlapse with heroku's router timeouts. According to heroku's docs I need writes to occur well under 1sec

Comment: There is no reason it should take 30 seconds to do maintenance on 9 indexes, unless this is to a large number of rows.  What are these writes?  INSERT?  UPDATE?  COPY?  Can you share the actual statement?  If there are multiple things which cause similar problem, pick the simplest concrete one and dig into it.  You won't get an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output on a failed query, so pick one which is slow but doesn't actually fail.

Answer (score 0):

Eitan Blumin has recently released [Drop All Redundant Indexes In Every Database All At Once](https://eitanblumin.com/2023/02/26/drop-all-redundant-indexes-in-every-database-all-at-once/)

It's a 300 lines of code script and you have to port it from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

There is one [less complicated](https://github.com/MadeiraData/MadeiraToolbox/blob/master/Best%20Practices%20Checklists/Redundant%20Indexes.sql) but it has to be ported too.

You can go into a step by step deep dive with this [article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/finding-and-eliminating-duplicate-or-overlapping-indexes-1).

Sorry, I haven't found any out-of-the-box tool for you.